# Node.js record date is greater than the current client date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

When i write data in mongodb for the recording date i use new Date() in node.js and i return that date with ajax response. To calculate the time elapsed from the moment the data in mongodb i create a new date on the client side. Then i calculate the difference between the current date and the date of which came from the server.

Here is my code:

```
var now = new Date();
var post_date = new Date(date_from_server);
var elapsed = now - post_date/1000;
document.write(elapsed + " seconds elapsed");
```

But, unknown to me, the recording date is greater than the current date, and the difference between them for the first time has a value of -40 seconds!

Please help me to understand this point. I guess that's something I'm doing wrong. But what's wrong?

Comment: Are the system clocks synchronised?

Comment: No. But i use timestamp

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I just got the news from server admin - he said that the server time was a deviation of 40 seconds :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the time setup between the server and client is different. You may try to emit a getFinalTime event to server, where the second time is recorded and returned to client for calculation.

Comment: It's obvious. :) But is the date received from the server may be earlier than the date after it generated?

Comment: @VladimirTitsky for example, if the time on the server is today and the time on the client is yesterday, you'll end up getting a 1 day difference.

Comment: I understand that. But server time is today and client time (in my case) is server time + few seconds spent waiting for a response from the server

Comment: @VladimirTitsky `var now = new Date();` gets just the time in your client computer. Different client computer has different local time, which is not synchronized with server.

Comment: The fact that they are not synchronized perfectly normal. I use the timestamp on the server: var now = new Date() - clien-side date and var post_date = new Date(_date_from_server_) so I get a date corresponding to the time the client computer

Comment: @VladimirTitsky I updated my answer. Suppose you get a brand new computer as a client, the initial time on it is 01/01/2000. What you will get if you connect to the server with it?